# Is it possible to highlight the unselectable item in the list box on mouse hover?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a list box with item templates and linked it to a list below is a simplified version of it.
These items are now selectable and highlight on mouse hover but I want to make them unselectable.
if I change the focusable property in style to false then it is not highlighted on mouse hover.

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" x:Uid="ListBox1" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  .
  .
  .
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>  
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add a PreviewMouseDown handler and return true to prevent them from being clicked on. They would still be selectable with the keyboard though.